# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 't', can someone help me correct this code?

Tags: google-play, sqlite3-python, alpaca

i want to loop and iterates over a list of symbols in chunks and retrieves daily bars data using my alpaca API credentials. Then inserts the retrieved data into a database table named stock_price using SQL INSERT statements.

[i run the code and was expecting the bars for the symbols with unique identification to download into my database techy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY1WR.png)